# stop visual studio from formatting code

Tags: html, visual-studio, autocomplete, autocorrect

How do you stop visual studio 2013 from formatting code

visual studio is inserting spaces after colons in my inline styles in a html file, which breaks it.

```
<div style=float:left;width:150>
```

It puts spaces after the colons

I know I could put the style in quotes, or use a stylesheet, but I don't want to.

Is it possible to stop VS from messing with your code?

Comment: That's invalid HTML. You *must* put the style in quotes. That's how tag attributes work

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML (Web Forms) > Formatting` and configure the formatting options you want.

Also, keep in mind that your "code" isn't actually valid html, attribute values should be wrapped in quotes.  That's why it's messing with your spaces.

```
<div style="float:left;width:150">
```

Comment: As an identical question keeps popping up for the last 1 hour, I'll just add that the problem is about *completion* not formatting. It *is* possible to close HTML attribute insertion from "HTML > Advance > Insert attribute value quotes". Tools like Resharper can also interfere though and try to format or fix invalid HTML.