# stop visual studio from auto completing code

Tags: visual-studio

I want to stop visual studio from auto inserting any code at all.

For example when editing html, I add style=
Visual studio then adds quotes. I don't want it to do this.

Neither do I want visual studio to alter my code in any way.

Is it possible to stop visual studio from changing my code?

Comment: Are you just going to keep asking this question over and over again until you get an answer you like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [stop visual studio from formatting code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276175/stop-visual-studio-from-formatting-code)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable auto-completion, and other intellisense features per-language in the text editor. Here are instructions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ecfczya1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Note: the location of the options may vary slightly depending on the version of Visual Studio you are using. The link is for VS 2010, but they are still valid up to (at least) VS 2013.